# Find the definite integral

Tags: definite-integrals

Find the definite integral

$$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{(3x-1)(2x+3)}{x} dx$$

I have come to an answer of $16 - \ln(8)$ which I think is very wrong..

First used integration by  parts

Comment: Open brackets and solve directly. Remember that (ln(x))' = 1/x.

Comment: can someone tell me what code I need to put in so the  x comes underneath?

Comment: @joe I can't edit your post to fix the latex, but you can look at the code on my answer for how all of that is done.  Or just to get fractions in general, you want \frac{numerator}{denominator}.  So, here you type: \int_1^2 \frac{(3x-1)(2x+3)}{x}.  with dollar signs, of course.

Comment: It's done now, I get what you mean mate it's just a bit confusing lol

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If I'm interpreting your question correctly, your answer is right.  A full derivation is as follows:

\begin{align*}
 \int_1^2 \frac{(3x-1)(2x+3)}{x} \, dx &= \int_1^2 \frac{6x^2 + 7x -3}{x} \, dx \\
  &= \int_1^2 6x \, dx + \int_1^2 7 \, dx - \int_1^2 \frac{3}{x} \, dx \\
  &\phantom{=} \\
  &= 6 \left. \frac{x^2}{2} \right|_1^2 + 7 x \biggr \rvert_1^2 - 3 \ln x \biggr \rvert_1^2 \\
  &\phantom{=} \\
  &= 6\left( \frac{4}{2} - \frac{1}{2} \right) + 7(2-1) - 3 (\ln 2 - \ln 1) \\
  & \phantom{=} \\
  & = 16 - 3 \ln 2 \\
  & = 16 - \ln 2^3 \\
  & = 16 - \ln 8
\end{align*}

Answer (score 5):

$$\int_{1}^{2}\frac{6x^2+7x-3}{x}dx$$
$$=\int_{1}^{2}\left(6x+7-\frac{3}{x}\right)dx$$
$$=\left(3x^2+7x-3\ln |x|\right)_{1}^{2}$$
$$=\left(3(2)^2+7(2)-3\ln |2|-(3(1)^2+7(1)-3\ln |1|)\right)$$
$$=16-3\ln 2$$ $$=16-\ln 2^3=16-\ln 8$$

Answer (score 3):

$\displaystyle \int_{1}^{2}\frac{(3x-1)\cdot (2x+3)}{x}dx = \int_{1}^{2}\frac{6x^2+7x-3}{x}dx = \int_{1}^{2}6xdx+\int_{1}^{2}7dx-\int_{1}^{2}\frac{1}{x}dx$

$\displaystyle = [3x^2]_{1}^{2}+[7x]_{1}^{2}-[3\ln|x|]_{1}^{2} = 16-3\ln(2)$

Answer (score 2):

expanding the integrad and dividing by $x$ we get $$\int_{1}^{2}7+6x-\frac{3}{x}dx$$
the indefinite integral is given by $$7x+3x^2-3\ln|x|+C$$